# YA fantasy book, girl with powers has to train in some kind of laboratory

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, powers

I remember reading this book a few years ago, maybe even about 9 years ago, so this book is not a new one.

A book for teenagers about a girl who lived in a laboratory because she had some powers (I don't remember exactly what kind of abilities).

She had to train to start controlling them and one day she met a boy who also had powers. I think someone had water power abilities.

I didn't read the whole book, so that's all I remember.